# Botões de positivar e negativar uma pergunta no meta, aparecem cortados

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Percebi isso hoje quando abri uma nova pergunta.

Pensei que fosse somente no meu tópico mas dei uma olhada rádida em outros e realmente aparece cortado em todos, inclusive nas respostas.

A imagem diz tudo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Claro que não é algo que podemos dizer "nossa ! que terrível, é o fim do mundo".. rsrs.. Até porque, com jeitinho dá para clicar nos botões.

Mas acho bom consertar. rsrs

SO: Windows 10.1 pro

Browser: Google Chrome last release

observações:

1. Não testei em outros sistemas ou browsers.
2. Verifiquei se o meu navegador estava com zoom, mas está em 100%.
3. No console não exibe nenhum erro javascript.

[Adicional]

Também reparei nas tags, o botão de remover uma tag, aparece desalinhado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]